# HLS (m3u8 file) getting stuck on seek

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am new to FFMPEG and my goal is to generate Adaptive Bitrate HLS variants for a given mp3 file.

Here's the command I am using for the same:

```
ffmpeg -i music_file.mp3 \
-hls_playlist_type vod -hls_time 4 -hls_flags single_file -b:a 160k ./audio/content-audio_high.m3u8 \
-hls_playlist_type vod -hls_time 4 -hls_flags single_file -b:a 90k ./audio/content-audio_med.m3u8 \
-hls_playlist_type vod -hls_time 4 -hls_flags single_file -b:a 24k ./audio/content-audio_low.m3u8
```

I am generating the master m8u8 manually with the following contents inside it.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-VERSION:4

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_group_med",NAME="my-audio-media-med",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="content-audio_med.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_group_high",NAME="my-audio-media-high",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="content-audio_high.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_group_low",NAME="my-audio-media-low",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="content-audio_low.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=96000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio_group_med"
content-audio_med.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=24000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio_group_low"
content-audio_low.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=160000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio_group_high"
content-audio_high.m3u8
```

I am then uploading all the files to the cloud and playing it using the master m8u8 which is this file `content-audio.m3u8`.
On playing the file in Safari, its playing smoothly until I seek the bar to forward. On seek the media hangs up abruptly.

Update:

In android, exo player was producing this block of text in logs

```
CCodecConfig: query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)


Codec2Client: query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
2021-11-30 15:53:06.087 29325-1123 W/Codec2Client: query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
2021-11-30 15:53:06.087 29325-1123 W/Codec2Client: query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
```

For details about the generated m3u8 files, here's the link to [all the files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f1DNjJE0_l-wcK1_lf8JJ96Cix9Qgx1p?usp=sharing)

I am new to FFMPEG and I am really confused on what might be getting wrong

Comment: Try without `-hls_flags single_file` to see if it's related to HTTP range request support on the server.

Comment: Hey thanks, removing the flag is working and I am able to seek the media. But what if I want to keep a single file? Curious to understand why requests are failing. Is it due to variable segment length of m3u8 file?

Comment: When you use `single_file` it uses byte offsets to delimit the media segments and the server on which you are hosting must support [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) to be able to serve them. Check if it's the case.

Comment: I can see that the range requests are getting 206 as response. Have a look here: 
`status: 206
Content-Type: video/mp2t
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 07:50:56 GMT
Expires: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 08:54:04 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 07:54:04 GMT
Content-Length: 53392
ETag: "75257105e8084b1a76291cea99185dee"
Content-Range: bytes 32444100-32497491/45900576`

I was testing on Safari and on seek the player was stuck but HTTP requests were getting successful

Comment: Could you try to see if the seek works with a single quality, so just load one of the variant playlists directly?

Comment: Yes I tried playing the variants independently as well and I get to see the same behaviour for all the 3 different variants